# How can explain the relation between mdlDerivatives output and mdlOutputs in S-function simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, s-function

I am new in Simulink and have a model which is used the S-function. I can not understand how the output of the mdlDerivatives relates to the outputs of the mdlOutputs? In another word, If I want to write a mfile(without using Simulink) what are the states and what are the outputs? I want to write a mfile and find ddq, dq and q but do not get how states in these two parts make the output?(file attached)

```
function [sys,x0,str,ts]=s_function(t,x,u,flag)
switch flag,
case 0,
e[sys,x0,str,ts]=mdlInitializeSizes;
case 1,
sys=mdlDerivatives(t,x,u);
case 3,
    sys=mdlOutputs(t,x,u);
case {2, 4, 9 }
    sys = [];
otherwise
    error(['Unhandled flag = ',num2str(flag)]);
end

function [sys,x0,str,ts]=mdlInitializeSizes
sizes = simsizes;
sizes.NumContStates  = 4;
sizes.NumDiscStates  = 0;
sizes.NumOutputs     = 4;
sizes.NumInputs      = 2;
sizes.DirFeedthrough = 0;
sizes.NumSampleTimes = 0;
sys=simsizes(sizes);
x0=[0;0;0;0];
str=[];
ts=[];
function sys=mdlDerivatives(t,x,u)
q1=x(1);dq1=x(2);
q2=x(3);dq2=x(4);
dq=[dq1;dq2];

% The model is given by Slotine and Weiping Li(MIT 1987)
alfa=6.7;beta=3.4;
epc=3.0;eta=0;
m1=1;l1=1;
lc1=1/2;I1=1/12;
g=9.8;
e1=m1*l1*lc1-I1-m1*l1^2;
e2=g/l1;

H=[alfa+2*epc*cos(q2)+2*eta*sin(q2),beta+epc*cos(q2)+eta*sin(q2);
   beta+epc*cos(q2)+eta*sin(q2),beta];
C=[(-2*epc*sin(q2)+2*eta*cos(q2))*dq2,(-epc*sin(q2)+eta*cos(q2))*dq2;
   (epc*sin(q2)-eta*cos(q2))*dq1,0];
G=[epc*e2*cos(q1+q2)+eta*e2*sin(q1+q2)+(alfa-beta+e1)*e2*cos(q1);
   epc*e2*cos(q1+q2)+eta*e2*sin(q1+q2)];

tol(1)=u(1);
tol(2)=u(2);

ddq=inv(H)*(tol'-C*dq-G);
sys(1)=x(2);
sys(2)=ddq(1);
sys(3)=x(4);
sys(4)=ddq(2);
function sys=mdlOutputs(t,x,u)
sys(1)=x(1);
sys(2)=x(2);
sys(3)=x(3);
sys(4)=x(4);
```

Comment: The output of this block coincides with its state. `mdlOutputs` receives the second argument `x` (this `x` is the state of the system) and returns it in `sys`

Answer (score 0):

A non-linear state-space model is comprised of 2 equations:

x_dot = f(x,u,t)

y = g(x,u,t)

If the system is linear this reduces to the (perhaps more familiar form)

x_dot = A * x + B * u

y = C * x + D * u

For a level-1 m-code S-Function (which is what you have), when Simulink wants the block's state derivative to be calculated it calls `mdlDerivatives`, and when it wan't the block's outputs it calls `mdlOutputs`.

That is `mdlDerivatives` implements the above equation for `x_dot`, and `mdlOutputs` implements the above equation for `y`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation